# Should we more narrowly define the scope of this stack?

Tags: discussion

What made me wonder this is this question:

[How do radio jammers work?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/22369/how-do-radio-jammers-work/22370#22370)

Is this about radio technology?  Yes.  Is it something an amateur radio operator likely has knowledge about?  Probably.  Is it something that should be entertained in this forum?  I'm not exactly certain.  My inclination is "No," but I thought it would be good to get a wider view.

Comment: hi David, i’m curious to understand what specifically about the question you perceived to be not quite right; I think there’s some unexplored (or perhaps merely unshared) nuance that I’d love to tease out and understand.

Comment: Even though I provided an answer, it felt like the question itself could raise sensitivities in governments and other organizations interested in monitoring the type of activities that the question was about.  I'm likely just being paranoid. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answers that question has drawn. They contain just as much information about how radio communication *succeeds* as how it might be prevented. Sure, we don't want to *encourage* anyone to build a jammer, but it's not like answering the question as stated makes that any significantly easier. I think it's turned out great for “demystifying” some elements of radio communication.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Kevin on this one - we should certainly not be *encouraging* the jamming of any radio signals, but in discussing how signals can be jammed we are also discussing how jamming can be avoided.

Jammers are definitely within scope of the "technology of radio", and as such it is considered an "on topic" subject for ham.SE. I can't think of another SE where it would be considered on topic.